# How long does it take to insert a full planet in database?

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap

I'm trying to insert a full [OpenStreetMap planet file](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm) into a postgreSQL database using the [osmosis](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis) tool, and I wonder how long will it take.

Actually, I'm *currently* inserting the full planet into a database but it has been running for more than 72 hours now, I was wondering how long it will be.

Thank you.

Comment: You should have chosen a *small* planet

Comment: Time how long it takes to insert 2 planets. Then just half that time. This should be a fairly good approximation 8-)

Comment: I would think that you have a better chance of getting an answer at gis.stackexchangs.com. Those guys might have tried that.

Comment: haha thank you all for your very accurate answer :) next time I'll try to live on a smaller planet :)

Comment: This seems like a perfectly reasonable question to me. I don't know why it has been closed as 'not a real question'. Perhaps because the terminology 'planet file' and 'osmosis' are not widely known. I've (tried to) edit the question to add links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard/impossible to estimate time interval without knowing any data about your hardware configuration and other details, but I found some [blog article](https://web.archive.org/web/20100812120522/http://www.adamestrada.com/2010/03/30/openstreetmap-planet-osm-processing-statistics/) (from march 2010, so probably you have bigger dump) and you can compare to yours.

> The whole process took approximately
> 89 hours to run...

Comment: I don't know how I missed it. Thank you very much.